# How to configure android logs based on build variant

Tags: android

I want to enable disable the logs based on build variant.
e.g. I want to enable the logs in debug mode and disable the logs in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer. I was trying since two days. So I am writing the working solution. So others can immediate solution.
Here are working solution.

first way.

1. create a prop file inside app. e.g. proguard-disabling-logs.pro
   add below code in that.
   -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log{*;}
2. go to your app level gradle file.
   buildTypes {
   release {
   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-disabling-logs.pro','proguard-rules.txt'
   }
   }
   }
   debug {
   proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   }
   }

This will disable logs in release mode and enable the logs in debug mode.

Second way:

1. go to app level gradle file add below code.
   buildTypes {
   release {
   buildConfigField "Boolean", "isLogEnabled", "false"
   }
   debug {
   buildConfigField "Boolean", "isLogEnabled", "true"
   }
   }

isLogEnabled is custom variable, you can rename whatever you want. Only add in existing code. Don't remove existing code inside debug/release block.
2. Build the code. It will create a isLogEnabled field inside BuildConfig class.
3. Now keep condition before log. e.g.
if(BuildConfig.isLogEnabled)
Log.d(TAG,"test")